# What is the origin of the idea to cover genitals with clothes or other materials?

Tags: ancient-history, clothing, anthropology

This question was difficult to word. Please edit if it can be worded better.

I've seen many murals and ancient drawing as far back as 3,000BC (Kemetian, Sumerian) of society wearing atleast some clothing to cover their genitals (and/or breasts of women). I've also seen primitive tribes of modern day, some who cover, some who are topless, and some who are totally naked.

What exactly was the origin and reasoning behind societies/civilizations adopting such clothing (i.e. covering a precise part of the body)?

I'm thinking before most common religions came into practice, that make covering obligatory.

Comment: While the question is interesting, the [history of clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_clothing_and_textiles) stretches 100-500k years back. There seems to be [a few theories](https://www.textileschool.com/4639/origin-of-clothing/) floating around about what you're asking but they're rather speculative.

Comment: Not only "primitive tribes" go totaly naked, [but civilized 1st world people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturism) too.

Comment: I am voting to reopen. While the question should be more precise, possibly specifying the regional context (middle east?), I cannot see how this is off topic. As a sidenote: The question as I understand it is not about the history of clothing, but about that of modesty (not keeping warm, adornment etc, but covering genitals).

Comment: I also vote to reopen. It is true that strictly speaking this question belongs to anthropology rather than history, but we do not have a convenient site for anthropology. While the question seems very interesting. Perhaps someone will post reasonable references.

Comment: Though, this might be considered a personal attack, but you guys better check out his profile. He **never** accepted any answer how many popular his question was, he verryyy ( as far as I checked, only one ) rarely leaves a comment, so don't be fooled, as I would like to caution you.

Comment: We've discussed at length the limitations of pre-historical sources, but I am skeptical that there is an answer to this question.

Comment: The simple answer is that we don't know.  The earliest archaeological evidence for clothing is a needle (found in Denisova Cave) made from animal bone that probably dates from ~50K years ago.  We have no way of knowing what those clothes were made from, or what parts of the body that clothing was intended to cover.  The clothing itself just doesn't survive.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yeah, this question belongs to more archaeology but there is no archaeology SE here so this question be better asked such as at reddit.

Comment: I imagine the same reason construction workers wear hardhats.....combined with natural selection.

Comment: @KentaroTomono  I think my point was rather that we don't have any actual evidence for the clothing, never mind what parts of the body it was intended to cover.  Absent the evidence for clothing, it really doesn't make sense to ask for the origins of clothing intended to cover particular parts of the body.  Even on Reddit.

Comment: Even if History doesn't know, this is a good history question and answering that History doesn't know would be a good answer.

Comment: @Pere And then you are obliged to make the complete, objective ( subjective ) answer by yourself.

Comment: I'm not asking for the origin of clothing, rather why genitals were covered by most societies across the globe. We see this trend among Mayans (before Columbus), in ancient Egypt, in primitive modern day tribes (some of whom are rarely contacted by outsiders). Maybe this question becomes more understandable if I ask the opposite: why don't societies wear a garb around their stomach and leave the rest of the body naked? <<That rarely happens, if ever.

Comment: @Kentaro Tomono I only comment where it seems appropriate and needed, and if I have something worthy of contribution. I'm not sure how to "accept an answer"; is there a button for that?

Comment: @Samid Oh sorry for that. The "accept" button is the very "check" button. It seems since your comments are so few, that answers may ( may be only to me ) think you don't care what answers made after they consumed a lot of time and effort. Please understand that.